# rewrite routes for URl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following URl:

```
http://localhost:12981/BaseEvent/EventOverview/12?type=Film
```

This is route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

I want that in a browser the url looks like:

```
http://localhost:12981/Film/Overview/12
```

How can I do this?

One more example:

```
http://localhost:12981/BaseEvent/EventOverview/15?type=Sport
```

should be

```
http://localhost:12981/Sport/Overview/15
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
routes.MapRoute("", "{type}/Overview/{id}", new { controller = "Events", action = "Overview");
```

Then you have a controller named `EventsController` with an action like this one

```
public ViewResult Overview(string type, int id)
{
   //Your code

   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Obviously you can change the controller anche action name with BaseEvent and EventOverview as per your example